# AHK scripts on IronAHK

Tags: autohotkey

How can I run AHK scripts on IronAHK?

Is this even possible?

Is there a method to convert scripts to IronAHK?

Thanks,

Odinulf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [road map](http://www.ironahk.net/docs/changes/#roadmap) the goal for version 1.0 is *Complete AutoHotkey compatibility on Windows*. So possibly you need to modify your script if it uses functionality not yet implemented.

See also [development status](http://www.ironahk.net/docs/developing/status/) and [AutoHotkey compatibility](http://www.ironahk.net/docs/autohotkey/).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [development status](http://www.ironahk.net/docs/developing/status/) mentioned by Wimmel you'll see that it's far from complete.  IronAHK isn't ready for use.

There are two alternatives: running AutoHotkey in WINE, and using a virtual Windows OS.  WINE doesn't allow any hotkeys, sending keys, etc.  It does let you make GUIs and do string processing.

Running in an emulator lets you have a full Windows desktop in a window and you can set any permissions you like, such as sharing folders with your host and manipulating the clipboard.  VMWare and VirtualBox are both popular for this.  You do need a Windows installation disk for these.